# Показать pdf ,сохраненный в базе данных через веб интерфейс

Tags: java, postgresql, mvc

Собственно вопрос такой,есть сервер на котором крутится приложение спринг бут с базой постгрес,в базе лежат пдф файлы в виде бай массивов.
Как мне показать пользователю эти пдф файлы?
Ведь прежде чем отобразить  пдф файл в браузере где то должен сохранится этот файл и я должен получить на него ссылку

Answer (score 1):

Просто посылаете этот массив байтов с правильным `Content-Type` в HTTP заголовках. Для PDF это `application/pdf`. В Spring есть уже готовая константа: `org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE`